# Select or Click event for a TreeView Child node

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a treeview control in asp.net. It has multiple parents nodes and under each parent node, there are multiple child nodes. When I select a parent node (click on it) a TreeView event called TreeView1_SelectedNodeChanged is triggered. I can write custom code based on requirements. What I am looking for is "On Select" or "On Click" for a Child node. I do not see any events for a child tree node. How do I do this? Although I can write code for Parent node click, I dont see anything for child node click or select.

Comment: i'm not sure about this, but are you looking for TreeViewItem.Selected ? if not, can you provide some code?

Comment: @darkSquirrel: Parent node is clicked and SelectedNodeChanged event is fired. Child node is clicked, nothing happens. I want to capture a child node "select" or "click" event. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

When you add the child node you can set the SelectAction:

```
child.SelectAction = TreeNodeSelectAction.Select
```

That should do it.

Comment: This does not do anything. The child node click does not trigger any event? How can I capture a click event on a child node of a treeview control? please help